# Set secondaryOk in script

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to run the `remove` command in the script file in the secondary node but it shows the `NotWritablePrimary` error:

Script:

```
rs.secondaryOk();
use foo;
db.getCollection('users').remove({accountId: 123456});
```

Shell command:

```
mongo -u <user> -p <password> < /path/to/script.js
```

Here's my configuration:

```
OS: Amazon Linux 2
Mongo 5.0.4 replication-mode with 3 nodes
```

Comment: You cannot modify any data on SECONDARY. Connect to the PRIMARY or specify the Replica Set in the connection string, then the client will select the primary.

Comment: you can call write operation on secondaries only for aggregation `$out`/`$merge` stages: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-merge, operation will still be called on primary, but it will be a server responsibility to send this command from secondary to primary